# direct sums and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that if $V=X\oplus Y$ is the direct sum of $X$ and $Y$, then $\dim V=\dim X+\dim Y$ if $V$ is a vector space of finite dimension.

But, what would happen in infinite dimension?

Comment: Doesn't that fall under functional analysis?

Comment: Same thing happens in infinite dimension, but the sum on the right hand side is a sum of cardinals. This assuming the Axiom of Choice, so that “dimension” makes sense.

Comment: I really don't know, I've seen it in a linear algebra book

Comment: @Shamim: Not if the spaces are not assumed to be normed or have an inner product... There is plenty of linear algebra in infinite dimensions that is not functional analysis.

Comment: Oh, i said it as it was quoted in axler's book. Honestly i know nothing of infinite dimensional vector spaces.